# Find root of implicit function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, root, implicit

I have an implicit function, for example:

```
f(x,y) = x**y + y**y - 3*x
```

I want to solve the root on a meshgrid. So f(x,y) = 0

Drawing the solution is easy:

```
x = linspace(-2,2,11)
y = linspace(-2,2,11)
(X,Y) = meshgrid(x,y)

A = X**Y + Y**Y - 3*X
contour(X,Y,A,0)
```

This works great, I have a drawing of the curve I need, however I would like to have the data that is in the plot and not only the visual plot. So how do I find the data of the plot?

Comment: What data exactly are you looking for? Are you trying to find points at which the function has a value of zero?

Comment: Is it restricted to polynomials only?

Comment: NumPy helps you find roots of polynomials. For a general function you would have to use numeric methods ... the answer is probably simple, but please do tell us if you care about just a special case or more than that.
http://www.scipy.org/doc/numpy_api_docs/numpy.lib.polynomial.poly1d.html

Comment: Im am trying to draw a function at value zero. The real function I am using is implicit and has some exponential components. So not only polynomials. It seems to be a simple case of calculating the roots over a meshgrid, nothing very exiting but I am not a mathematics guru at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get "the data that is in the [matplotlib] plot" using:

```
cs = contour(X,Y,A,0)
data = cs.collections[0].get_paths()[1]
```

There are a variety of algorithms for calculating the contours directly, though I don't know of any numpy/scipy versions.  [Marching squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) is the one I always here about, although the algorithm is patented and there are severe restrictions on it's use, so I doubt matplotlib uses it.  [Here's](http://osdir.com/ml/python.matplotlib.devel/2005-07/msg00005.html) a link with a bit of chat on how matplotlib calculates the contours.

Comment: I get the following error: IndexError: list index out of range
Where do I find this class information. I think  I can figure it out myself, but somehow I am unable to find the description of all classes

Comment: It worked: data = cs.collections[0].get_paths()[0] 
Thanks a lot, still I would like to know where I find this information myself, could you tell me?

Comment: Enrico - I'm not sure whether you want more info on this... but how I work stuff like this out is that I use an interactive environment like ipython, and if I want access to things in a plot I start by getting the return value ("cs" here).  Then I do "help cs", and look over what's available in cs and go for the most promising ("collections" here), and I just work my way down this way.  When I end up with the paths, as here, the docs are right there when I use "help" again.